# Call a dynamic variable in R

Tags: r, dynamic

This below code does not work because R does not know what to do with fieldname.

```
min_a_column <- function(filename, fieldname){
  a <- min(filename$fieldname)
  return(a)
}
ans <- sum_a_column(B, Date)
print(paste0("ans = ",ans))
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

The error I get is:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"min_a_column <- function(filename, fieldname){
  a <- min(filename"$fieldname""
```

The other half a dozen links I get using the keyword dynamic variables do not give me the right results.  What should the keywords be to search for this?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `[[` instead of `$` `min(filename[[fieldname]])` and pass fieldname as string.  also, if the function name is `min_a_column` `min_a_column(B, "Date")`

Answer (score 0):

```r
min_a_column <- function(filename, fieldname){
  a <- min(filename[[fieldname]])
  return(a)
}
ans <- sum_a_column(B, Date)
print(paste0("ans = ",ans))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.